# How to align search bar in center of nav bar

Tags: html, css

In this below given code, I am trying to align search box in center of navbar but it doesn't work. How I align search bar in center of navbar:

```css
#navbar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: aqua;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  font-size: 1.3em;
}

#search {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#faviorites {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<nav id="navbar">
  <a id="home" href="/">Home</a>
  <input type="text" id="search" placeholder="Search Here">
  <a href="fav.html" id="faviorites">Faviorites</a>
</nav>
```

Comment: @Amaresh S M answer is not accurate. it stretches the search bar. Also there's no need to have floats when flexbox is used. I have cleaned up your css and added a better solution and example Fiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add  `display:flex;` to `#navbar`.

```css
#navbar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  display:flex;
  background-color: aqua;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  font-size: 1.3em;
}

#search {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#faviorites {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<nav id="navbar">
  <a id="home" href="/">Home</a>
  <input type="text" id="search" placeholder="Search Here">
  <a href="fav.html" id="faviorites">Faviorites</a>
</nav>
```

if you want to center both horizontally and vertically use:

```
#navbar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
  background-color: aqua;
}
```

Comment: please don't add irrelevant tag to the question. Using flexbox as a solution doesn't make the question related to flexbox

Comment: okay @TemaniAfif

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to use a flexbox and define `space-between` for horizontal spacing.

```css
#navbar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: aqua;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  font-size: 1.3em;
}
```

```html
<nav id="navbar">
  <a id="home" href="/">Home</a>
  <input type="text" id="search" placeholder="Search Here">
  <a href="fav.html" id="faviorites">Faviorites</a>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easily using flexbox

**Add** these 3 to your `#navbar` and that's all needed.

```
#navbar {
   display: flex;
   justify-content: space-between;
   align-items: flex-start;
   /*your current styles*/
}
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kdvy60Lu/7/)